# Generate multiple files with laravel command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

could you help me with a problem that I have? I have created a command with `php artisan make:command` to generate repository type classes from existing models. The problem is that I need that instead of generating a single file from a stub, I need to generate 2 or more files. I can't find documentation regarding the subject. Currently what I have achieved is that I only generate a single file from a template.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class MakeRepository extends GeneratorCommand
{
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'make:repository';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create a new repository';

    /**
     * The type of class being generated.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type = 'Repository';

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function getStub()
    {
        return __DIR__ . '/stubs/MakeRepository/ModelRepositoryInterface.stub';
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return [
            ['name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The name of the model to which the repository will be generated'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the default namespace for the class.
     *
     * @param string $rootNamespace
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getDefaultNamespace($rootNamespace)
    {
        return $rootNamespace.'\Repositories';
    }
}
```

**EDIT #1**

I have 2 stub files inside the directory:

`app/Console/Commands/stubs/MakeRepository`

```
ModelRepository.stub
ModelRepositoryInterface.stub
```

I want that when you execute the command...ex: `php artisan make:repository Blog`, these 2 files are created in the following directory:

```
/app/Repositories/Blog/BlogRepository.php
/app/Repositories/Blog/BlogRepositoryInterface.php
```

Comment: What are the files you're wanting to create?

Comment: @Rwd Thanks for answering, please see my Edit #1

Answer (score 1):

You can write a new command to create repository interface, and then call it in MakeRepository.

I think this method is in line with SRP.

```
// In MakeRepository.php

// Override handle method
public function handle()
{
    if (parent::handle() === false && ! $this->option('force')) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->option('interface')) {
        $this->call('make:repository-interface', ['name' => $this->getNameInput() . 'Interface']);

    }
}

/**
 * Get the console command arguments.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getArguments()
{
    return [
        ['name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The name of the model to which the repository will be generated'],
        ['interface', 'i', InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Create a new interface for the repository'],
    ];
}
```

You can also refer to the code of make model of official.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ModelMakeCommand.php

Comment: This solution looks great, but the ideal would be to have it in a single command, and pass it an argument to define whether or not to create the interface for that repository, ex: ```php artisan make:repository Blog --interface ```, anyway, for now your answer seems like a possible solution

Comment: If you only want to write in one command, you may need to override more `GeneratorCommand` methods or write a new one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use glob to get your stubs in array then loop over them to create the multiple files**

```
foreach(glob(stubs_path('stubs/Repository/*.stub') as $stub){
            copy(stubs_path('stubs/Repository/'.$stub), $repositoryLocation . 'Repository.php');
}
```